# SwiftUI - changes in nested View Model classes not detected using onChange method

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a nested View Model class `WatchDayProgramViewModel` as an ObservableObject. Within `WatchDayProgramViewModel`, there is a `WorkoutModel` that is a child class. I want to detect any updates in the  `currentHeartRate` to trigger data transfer to iPhone.

Hence, I tried from ContentView using `WatchDayProgramViewModel` as an `EnvironmentObject` and detecting changes in `WorkoutModel` via `onChange()` method. But it seems that SwiftUI views does not detect any property changes in `WorkoutModel`.

I understand that this issue could be due to ObservableObject not detecting changes in child/nested level of classes, and SO answer ([SwiftUI change on multilevel children Published object change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67458336/swiftui-change-on-multilevel-children-published-object-change)) suggests using `struct` instead of class. But changing `WorkoutModel` to `struct` result in various `@Published` properties and functions to show error.

**Is there any possible way to detect changes in child View Model from the `ContentView` itself?**

ContentView

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selectedTab = 0
    @StateObject var watchDayProgramVM = WatchDayProgramViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
    
        NavigationView {
TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                    
                    WatchControlView().id(0)
                    NowPlayingView().id(1)
                }
                .environmentObject(watchDayProgramVM)
                .onChange(of: self.watchDayProgramVM.workoutModel.currentHeartRate) { newValue in
                                        print("WatchConnectivity heart rate from contentView \(newValue)")
   
                }
       }
}
```

WatchDayProgramViewModel

```
class WatchDayProgramViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var workoutModel = WorkoutModel()
    
    init() {
    }
    
}
```

WorkoutModel

```
import Foundation
import HealthKit

class WorkoutModel: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    
    let healthStore = HKHealthStore()
    var session: HKWorkoutSession?
    var builder: HKLiveWorkoutBuilder?
    
    @Published var currentHeartRate: Double = 0
    @Published var workout: HKWorkout?

//Other functions to start/run workout hidden

func updateForStatistics(_ statistics: HKStatistics?) {
        
        guard let statistics = statistics else {
            return
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            switch statistics.quantityType {
            case HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .heartRate):
                
                let heartRateUnit = HKUnit.count().unitDivided(by: HKUnit.minute())
                
                self.currentHeartRate = statistics.mostRecentQuantity()?.doubleValue(for: heartRateUnit) ?? 0
                
            default:
                return
                
            }
            
        }//end of dispatchqueue
        
    }// end of function

}

extension WorkoutModel: HKLiveWorkoutBuilderDelegate {
    
    func workoutBuilder(_ workoutBuilder: HKLiveWorkoutBuilder, didCollectDataOf collectedTypes: Set<HKSampleType>) {
        
        for type in collectedTypes {
            guard let quantityType = type as? HKQuantityType else {
                return
            }

            let statistics = workoutBuilder.statistics(for: quantityType)
            updateForStatistics(statistics)
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: don't use view model objects and certainly don't nest them! Use @ State and @ Binding for transient view data and make a custom struct to hold related vars and have mutating funcs if you need to.

Comment: Thanks @malhal for advice, but I am almost done resolving the issue and just need to test on real-device before I post answer. I am using AnyCancellable to circumvent this issue. But aren't Combine & SwiftUI meant to work well with MVVM?

Comment: @malhal just curious, how would you circumvent scenarios where you need a class object, instead of a struct and you need them to be "nested"?

Comment: No SwiftUI does not work with MVVM. You can think of the View data struct as doing the job of a MVVM view model object. SwiftUI diffs these data structs and it creates and updates the UILabels etc on our behalf. So for transient view data we use the View struct. For the model we model our data with value types I.e. struct and manage life cycle with reference type I.e. ObservableObject.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/choosing_between_structures_and_classes “ Sharing class instances pervasively throughout an app makes logic errors more likely.“

Comment: @malhal thanks for the comments, I am still new to SwiftUI and will need to learn further. However, I did research and many sources has mentioned SwiftUI + Combine is a great choice for MVVM. https://iosapptemplates.com/blog/swiftui/mvvm-combine-swiftui/. Besides, my iPhone app is using MVVM, so I wanted to use the same approach to avoid confusion.

Comment: It's going to be very difficult for me to change the entire architecture at this point, especially when I tried to use structs first and faced issues, that were resolved by using Classes. But I will keep your advice in my mind and review my architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure it out. Just had to create another `AnyCancellable` variable to call `objectWillChange` publisher.

WatchDayProgramViewModel

```
class WatchDayProgramViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var workoutModel = WorkoutModel()
    var cancellable: AnyCancellable?

    init() {
        cancellable = workoutModel.objectWillChange
            .sink { _ in
                self.objectWillChange.send()
            }
    }
    
}
```

While I have provided my answer, that worksaround with viewmodels, I would love to see/get advice on other alternatives.

Comment: You are trying to implement your own dependency tracking instead of using SwiftUI’s built in. It’s best to remove the view model objects there is no need and will just cause problems. Best learn how to use the View structs, eg body called when a let changes and state/binding vars for write access.

Comment: @malhal thanks for the advice, I do think above is not the cleanest or more maintainable way to manage my objects, and I will review my architecture.

Comment: @malhal are you referring to something like IVO - smth similar shown here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SOA0IT7sxvc

Comment: Try this https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10040/

Comment: @malhal I have delved a little deeper and I think I am getting what you are saying. The SwiftUI views are not optimized for "reference" types, they rely a lot on value types. Combine and ObservedObject don't quite work well (they still do) with nested view models. As I am troubleshooting, I think I understand.

Comment: @malhal having said that, I am finding ways to utilize nested view models using Combine and Publishers, and restricting most SwiftUI views with one view model are working fine for me at this point. So, I think I pass using structs only and mutating functions for the time being.

Comment: @malhal After researching and talking to multiple developers, I came to conclusion that MVVM + SwiftUI + Combine approach is just fine, if we make use of publishers. It turns out even Apple engineers use them, so I think I will turn down your suggestion for good.

Comment: It does work but it using objects causes hard to track down bugs which SwiftUI and Swifts use of value types was designed to avoid so I think it’s best to use it the way it was designed if possible first before resorting to objects. I’ve also seen non SwiftUI Apple engineers not using it correctly which is concerning but not uncommon in any teams use if another teams framework.

Comment: @malhal thanks very much for your input and advice. Even if I am not taking your suggestion (largely because it would mean an overhaul of my app, and learning the other path of using SwiftUI), I have learnt a lot more about the SwiftUI framework with your comments!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
@StateObject var watchDayProgramVM = WatchDayProgramViewModel()
```

with

```
@ObservedObject var watchDayProgramVM = WatchDayProgramViewModel()
```

Comment: This doesn't work at all. I am using the view model class, so I think both objects work about the same. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62544115/what-is-the-difference-between-observedobject-and-stateobject-in-swiftui, but thanks much for the suggestion.